# Can a div have half image and half color background?

Tags: html, css

When I try this no color or image comes up:

```
 #example1 {
    background:blue:
    background: url(tin.jpg) repeat-y;
    background-size: 50% auto;
    width: 100%;
    height:400px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: use a semicolon after blue

Comment: Please try to give more details as to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You have to combine it like below.

```
 background:blue url(http://photos.state.gov/libraries/media/788/images/500x500-sample.jpg) repeat-y;
```

Or if you want to give separately, you have to give it like

```
background-color:blue;
background-image:url(http://photos.state.gov/libraries/media/788/images/500x500-sample.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat-y;
```

```css
 #example1 {   
   background:blue url(http://photos.state.gov/libraries/media/788/images/500x500-sample.jpg) repeat-y;
    background-size: 50% auto;
    width: 100%;
    height:500px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1">

</div>
```

Comment: or in his code he simple change to `background-color` and put it after

Answer (score 1):

You should only have one `background` definition. Currently, your second `background` overrides the first.

```css
#example1 {
    background: blue url(https://placehold.it/800x800) repeat-y;
    background-size: 50% auto;
    width: 100%;
    height:400px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to include your color background to image background like this :

```
background: blue url(tin.jpg) repeat-y;
```

so your style code should like this

```
#example1 {
  background: blue url(tin.jpg) repeat-y;
  background-size: 50% auto;
  width: 100%;
  height:400px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```